# infinity b'' problem running shell script throug flask

Tags: python, shell, flask

It's first time for ask question.

Inside the sh file, This can run virtualenv and Python files. The python file is a file for deep learning. It tooks a time.

I want to print out the output of Python file in real time on web page.
but when I using this code, there was printed infinity b'' lines after right output was printed.

Help me.

```
def uploaded():
    def inner():
        proc = subprocess.Popen('./some.sh', stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")

        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
            string = line.rstrip()
            print(string)
            yield string + b'<br/>\n'

        for line in iter(proc.stderr.readline,''):
            string = line.rstrip()
            print(string)
            yield string + b'<br/>\n'

    return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `readline` calls are returning `bytes` instances, but with your two-argument `iter` call, you're comparing it to the empty `str` instance, `''`, instead of the empty `bytes` instance, `b''`. Those are not equal, so the loop runs forever. Try doing the iteration with `iter(proc.stdout.readline, b'')`, and `iter(proc.stderr.readline, b'')`.